# Access Azure DevOps Group Vars as Enviroment Vars

Tags: bash, azure-devops, yaml, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

It is possible to access all vars from a azure DevOps variable group as environment vars in a bash step?

At best I want a way to access all group vars as environment var inside of a python script.

So something like the `yaml` below I have in mind, but open for other ideas. Right know I add every var from my group as an env param, but so I have always to update the azure DevOps `yaml` if I want to add a new var in the group. This just don't feel right....

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  - group: myGroup

stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
      - job: test
        displayName: Test
        steps:
          - bash: |
              echo $path.myGroup
            group:
              - myGroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. However you can try to use [azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group?view=azure-cli-latest) to fetch both names and values for non secret variables inside the group. It doesn't returna  value for you for secret variables, however for them you still have to map them explicit.

And if you do this:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
      - job: test
        displayName: Test
        variables:
        - group: myGroup
        steps:
          - bash: |
              echo 'You have all non secret variables ampped to env variables`
              echo `You can use Azure Cli to get all names of the mapped variables from variables group`
```

You will get all non-secret variables mapped.

You can also use

```
        variables:
        - group: myGroup
```

on the top level achieving the same, but then you will get it mapped accross all jobs.

Comment: Thanks , in my case, I also want to access secret variables.
I will take a look into the azure CLI, it look like there are hidden power for the pipeline 